# Exporting Database Query to CSV file, PostgreSQL & Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, postgresql, csv

As the title states, I'm exporting a java query from a local database into a CSV file, all the required information prints out correctly, however my column headers Print out in Column A (row 1-8) and not along columns (A-H). in short i have headers 1-8 printing in column 1, followed by thousands of rows of data in the correct order. Pretty new to java, sorry if I'm being silly!

```
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("TestingRawData.csv")));

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
            String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            out.println(name);
            // print the name
        }

        while (result.next()) {
            out.println(String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",
                    result.getString(1), result.getString(2),
                    result.getString(3), result.getString(4),
                    result.getString(5), result.getString(6),
                    result.getString(7), result.getString(8)));

        }
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but each datafield should be surrounded by double quotes. That prevents any problems caused by commas in your data.

Comment: Thank you, will sort it just now

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that this should be done using a CSV library such as OpenCSV, 
`println` outputs a newline. Use `print` instead

```
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
    String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    out.print(name);
    if (i != columnCount + 1) {
      out.print(",");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply =), now it prints my 8 table headers one after another in Column A row 1

Comment: You'll need to output the separators yourself - that's why using a CSV library is soo much better :)

Comment: Thanks man! works now, all headers are showing, i will have a look at the CSV library, i was reading about that somewhere so i will change it, do you have any idea why now Columns I-P contain data? just one row, showing up as headers (when they should be blank) thank you again

Comment: As well as OpenCSV, also look at JacksonCSV mapper for a CSV library.